# Renaming numbered files for proper sorting

Tags: c#, strings, .net

I have designed a tool that generates some HTML files and a CSS file in a directory, which then feed into a tool called Jutoh that uses these to make eBooks.

However, my output files are of the form 1.htm, 2.htm and so on. Jutoh ranks 10.htm to preceed 2.htm and therefore, I wrote a method to convert 1.htm into 0001.htm. I would like to know your opinion on it and learn where there might be scope for speedup and other improvements.

```
var inputDir = _cssFile.Directory.FullName + "\\Output\\";
var outputDir = _cssFile.Directory.FullName + "\\Output";
if (!Directory.Exists(outputDir))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(inputDir);
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles("*.htm"))
{
    string n = fi.Name.Replace(fi.Extension, ""); //remove extension
    int k = Int32.Parse(n); //Convert string to int
    string t = k.ToString("D4"); //convert it into 4 digit
    t = t + fi.Extension; // add extension

    string trgtfile = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, t);
    File.Move(fi.FullName, trgtfile);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Is there a lot of surrounding code? You might get more/better feedback if you include your entire method's body (and signature).

Comment: You could gain a lot of simplicity by using the `Pad` method available to strings, rather than converting the string to an integer and formatting it back into a string.

Comment: @Mat'sMug : Thank you for an interesting question. There isn't much surrounding code. The core logic is to solve the problem of the numbering where 10 precedes 2 .

Comment: @tinstaafl   : Interesting observation. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are several tips that might help write better/cleaner code. Note that my tips or help might not be perfect but it gives you an idea on how to write better code.

- **Naming you variables**

Using variable names like `k` and `n` are very bad practice. Not only will other people not understand your code, if you haven't looked at your code for a while, you might have forgotten what each variable does/stands for. Give your variables a meaningful name. So after applying this, your code looks like this:

```
string currentName = fi.Name.Replace(fi.Extension, "");
int nameAsNumber = Int32.Parse(currentName);
string newName = nameAsNumber.ToString("D4");
newName = newName + fi.Extension;

string targetFile = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, newName);
File.Move(fi.FullName, targetFile );
```

- **Over-creating variables**

Storing operations/calculations on variables in new variables can be handy and even necessary in certain situations. But in this situation where you take a string, parse it to an int and make it a string again, I suggest you do this in one line. You can even add the extension in the same line:

```
string currentName = fi.Name.Replace(fi.Extension, "");
string newName = int.Parse(currentName).ToString("D4") + fi.Extension;
```

This does not mean you have to write *all* your code in one line, this an example of doing too much in one line:

```
string targetFile = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName)).ToString("D4") + fi.Extension);
```

The above line does exactly the same but it's not easy to read and/or maintain.

- **Re-inventing the wheel (part 1)**

Why create methods/functions/lines of code that do something that's already been made for you. If you want to get the filename without the extension, use the [**Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
string currentName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName);
```

- **Re-inventing the wheel (part 2)**

Remember, the .NET framework contains classes and methods for almost anything. And this also goes for adding zeros (or other characters) to a string when they do not yet meet a desired length. This is done with the `Pad()` method, and in your case the [**String.PadLeft(Int32, Char)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You simply provide the desired length and the character that will be put in place. Your code will become:

```
string currentName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName);
string newName = currentName.PadLeft(4, '0') + fi.Extension;
```

Your complete inside-loop code will now look like:

```
string currentName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName);
string newName = currentName .PadLeft(4, '0') + fi.Extension;
string targetFile = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, newName);
File.Move(fi.FullName, targetFile);
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. Accepting this answer.